# Passing a JavaScript variable in SQL Datasource in ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, data-binding

I have a java script variable and I want to use it into my sqldatasourse how can I do this. Here is my java script code

```
var div = document.getElementById('main_content').offsetHeight;
            var length = Mah.round(div / 400);
```

And I want to use variable length here in select command

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:qbuyConnectionString1 %>" 
         SelectCommand="SELECT TOP variable * FROM [advertisement] WHERE ([enable] = @enable) ORDER BY NEWID()">
        <SelectParameters><asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="enable" Type="Int32" /></SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Javascript runs on the client. SQL on the server. Your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You want some client side variable affect something in the server you need to send it there, ajax request is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution based on how you are trying to do this is a combination of some of the aforementioned suggestions.

1. Create a server-side ASP.NET hidden field control in your page.
2. Set the *server-side* hidden field control to the JavaScript variable value.
3. In the _Selecting event which fires prior to the database being accessed, set the 'Parameter' value to that of the hidden server-side control.

Step 1:

```
<!--Create an ASP.NET hidden field server control-->
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

Step 2:

```
//JavaScript you were using populating the 'length' variable:
var div = document.getElementById('main_content').offsetHeight;
var length = Mah.round(div / 400);
//Now set the hidden field's value to your JS variable value:
document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientId %>');
```

Step 3:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    //The 'Selecting' event fires *prior* to the wired up Select method being called.
    //This is the spot to add in or modify any of the parameter values:
    e.Command.Parameters["LengthParameter"].Value = this.HiddenField1.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your JS variable to your server using AJAX. Assuming your ASP page is called `query.asp`, you could use jQuery to do the following.

```
$.get('query.asp', {length: length});
```

Now your ASP page can access it like `Request.QueryString('length')`

Answer (score -1):

well you could create a hidden element and insert the value from js into it then read it from c# and insert it into the db.

the html

```
<input type="hidden" id="dataForSQL"></input>
```

the js

```
$('#dataForSQL').html(length);
```

Comment: ?! div instead of hidden? the most important thing how to connect the element to the server is missing.

Comment: only input fields are posted to the server.

Comment: hidden div was incorrect. I updated it to an `input`. From there he would actually submit it via AJAX to a controller.